# Is there a list of technical terms for angles shots are taken at?

Tags: terminology, field-of-view

I'm dealing with digital product (packaged goods) photos, and the data I get includes descriptions like "front", "front side right angle", "front side left angle", "top", "right", "left", "bottom", "back".

Is there a complete list of these terms?

Are there technical definitions of these terms? Like, maybe if an angle is taken from within 10 degrees of due-front, it's called "front" and otherwise it's "front side right angle" or "front top" or something. (That's just an example.)

Comment: I'd avoid the pair of words "right angle" unless you mean a right angle as in 90 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

Not specific to product photography, but you could correctly borrow *general* terms from medicine and engineering to describe the physical aspects of most 3D objects. Such as:

- lateral
- medial
- proximal
- distal
- superior
- inferior
- anterior
- posterior

You can combine some of these terms to describe intermediate areas, such as distolateral (side-rear) or mediolateral (middle rear), but not *opposing* aspects like anterior (forward aspect) and posterior (rear aspect).

Just be sure to avoid using terms that are specific to anatomy or any other *specific* field of science.

Hooray for Latin - filling the gaps in the English language yet again.

Comment: Jut for fun: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_angle

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely you find a list or that there is even a complete list. You could look into architectural terms which have a more standardized usage but as far as photo is concerned, these are terms are mostly descriptive.

You will find things like top and bottom easier to distinguish but right and left are even a matter of point of view :) Usually image providers offer intermediate points such as front-top and front-left-top but this does not imply a minimal degree of inclination. The term 3/4 view is also often used but again it does not necessarily mean a 3/4 turn in any orientation.

Answer (score 0):

> Like, maybe if an angle is taken from within 10 degrees of due-front, it's called "front"...

Even if there were such a list, what guarantee would you have that the terms are being applied in accordance with the definitions?

Your best course of action is to go directly to the source of the data and find out what terms are used and how they're applied.

Comment: Yes, I know, but I am looking to standardize the data on my end, so a standard list of such terms would help. (I should have mentioned my end purpose in the question.) Thanks for the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a standard for photography, but a very clever aplication as seen on this video of a photographer called Michael is to use a clock model. The same you use if you were flying a jet fighter.

The subject at the center of the clock. You are at 6 o'clock. It is for lighting, but I'm sure you can do that with the camera aswell.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ktb_UjNBqwg